# Custom icon for a radio ant Design

Tags: reactjs, antd

Can someone help me, how to change icon radio like checkbox icon in ant Design table. Here my table code

```
<Table 
  rowSelection = {{
    type: "radio",
    buttonStyle: "solid",
    selectedRowKeys: this.state.keys,
    onChange: this.onRowKeysChange
  }}
  title = {() => < b > Classes < /b>} 
  bordered 
  components={this.components} 
  columns={columnsSegment2Active} 
  size="middle" 
  dataSource={this.state.data8} 
  loading={this.state.loading}/ >
```

Comment: Show your whole Table compoment.

Comment: Remove `type: "radio",`, it will change to checkbox :)

Comment: i only want checked in one checkbox, if i remove type: "radio".
every box can checked in same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change round shape of radio button to square, add the below css

```
.ant-radio-inner, .ant-radio-inner:after{
  border-radius: 0!important;
}
.ant-radio-inner:after{
  border: none!important;
}
```

Check the stackblitz implementation [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-suzxaq)

Comment: @kangketik there is an update in the css, this update is for bug in hover. Also please accept my answer if it helped you :)